# Issue in connecting "HTTPd" with " Tomcat"

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

Our system are using "mod_proxy_ajp", with Apache 2.0, httpd-2.2.3-43.el5, tomcat 7.0.
When we get log on the "httpd ", we have the logs as below:

> [Sun Oct 05 12:14:10 2014] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has
>   expired: ajp_ilink_receive() can't receive header
>
> [Sun Oct 05 12:14:10 2014] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive
>   failed
>
> [Sun Oct 05 12:14:10 2014] [error] (120006)APR does not understand
>   this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (xx.xx.xx.xx)

Besides, we don't receive the request message on the tomcat.
I think this issue appear due to the Connector between "HTTPd" and "Tomcat".
Can you tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: First start with trying if you can connect from Apache's server to tomcat's AJP port with something like telnet or netcat. If not you might have a configuration, firewall or router problem. Are you actually connecting to an AJP connector on the tomcat side (not HTTP(s))

Comment: This system is used for IVR service. And this issue not appear allway, sometime it'll come back to 2-3h later.

Comment: Do the problems correlate with GCs on tomcat or spikes in network error counts? (netstat -S - look for rejects and other errors). Are both systems on the same network segment?

Comment: Sounds like tomcat take too long time to process and nothing returns to proxy_ajp.

Answer (score 0):

You could give increasing the ProxyTimeout a try.

```
<VirtualHost ....>
...
ProxyTimeout 900
```